# Laravel orderby joining 2 tables without eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have 2 tables for a chatting system

**"users"** table structure:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |

**"messages"** table structure:

| id | sender_id | receiver_id | message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

I want to return friend users ordered by when there was chatting between you and friend last time.
Note: `id` works same as timestamp

Suppose,

| id | sender_id | receiver_id | message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `$userA->id` | `$userB->id` | abc |
| 2 | `$userC->id` | `$userA->id` | xyz |

So, If `$userA` is the logged in user - I want users to be returned like:

```
[
    0 => $userC,
    1 => $userB,
    2 => $userD,
    3 => $userE,
    4 => $userF,
    ...
]
```

(where `$userD`, `$userE`, `$userF` has no messages with user `$userA`)

Basically I want to return all the friend users sorted using if user has any message with logged in user.

My current code giving me some unexpected result -

```
return DB::table('users')->leftJoin('messages', function ($join) {
    $join->on('users.id', '=', 'messages.sender_id')
        ->where('messages.sender_id', auth()->id())
        ->orOn('users.id', '=', 'messages.receiver_id')
        ->where('messages.receiver_id', auth()->id());
})
->select('users.*')
->where('users.id', '!=', auth()->id())
->orderBy('messages.id', 'asc')
->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I can't be sure if this will work as I can't testi it, but I think code should be something like:

```
$messagesSent = DB::table('messages')
    ->select('sender_id as other_user', DB::raw('MAX(id) as last_message_id'))
    ->where('receiver_id', auth()->id())
    ->groupBy('sender_id');

$messagesSentOrReceived = DB::table('messages')
    ->select('receiver_id as other_user', DB::raw('MAX(id) as last_message_id'))
    ->where('sender_id', auth()->id())
    ->groupBy('receiver_id')
    ->union($messagesSent);

$usersWithCommunication = DB::table('users')
    ->select('other_user', DB::raw('MAX(last_message_id) as last_message_id'))
    ->joinSub($messagesSentOrReceived, 'latest_messages', function ($join) {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'latest_messages.other_user');
    })
    ->groupBy('other_user');
    

return DB::table('users')
    ->leftJoinSub($usersWithCommunication, 'latest_communications', function ($join) {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'latest_communications.other_user');
    })
    ->select('users.*')
    ->orderBy('latest_communications.last_message_id', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: It will only show users if any message exists. Actually I want these users at top and all the rest of users after. Your code solves my sorting problem. With this I also want rest of users at the bottom. Thank you

Comment: Finally I solved by using **leftJoinSub** in return

Comment: @DebarshiDas Edited my answer so it correctly answers question.
Did my code actually work without errors? I was sure I will mess something up as I couldn't actually test anything

Comment: I am having another problem here! Instead of loading all users, I am tying pagination. But when I do **paginate(10)** in return method instead of **get()** I always get one duplicate user with the other 9 users. But if I do **get()** then there are no duplicate users in the array. I can't figure out where the problem is!

Comment: @DebarshiDas it would be preferred if you created new question. You could get more answers and specify more info

Comment: I have added a new question - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66883117/duplicate-object-in-laravel-pagination)